# Google Sheets popup box if cell goes negative

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, messagebox, triggers

I am trying to figure out a script that will popup a box if a cell in a column goes negative. I need it to search column F and if any negative numbers are found its brings up a message box saying that there are negative numbers in column F. Here is the one I have been trying to modify but I cannot seem to get it to work. No popup at all. I am also not sure if this calculate negatives properly beyond the -0.1 (like it if was -1 instead of -0.1).

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
  if(sheet=="Numbers"){
     if(editedCell.getColumn() == 6 && event.value==-0.1){   
        Browser.msgBox('It looks like there is a negative number in Column F.');
  }}}
```

Any help would be appreciated and Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried `if (editedCell.getColumn() === 6 && event.value < 0)`?

Comment: Actually I didn't try that but it is working. I may have found my issue though. I am using a formula to generate the negative numbers and I think the 'onedit' function may be whats causing my issue. Do you know of an alternative to that reference that will work with formulas instead of someone typing in a negative number?

Comment: You should create a new question with all the information on your new issue.